# Camera overlay view mathematics with Lattitude and Longitude

Tags: iphone, latitude-longitude

I have been working on Augmented Reality application that displays predefined map-points on Camera overlayview with nicely generated frame windows per map-points which includes details about the map-point, image, and miles away from the current location. I have done everything successfully and now my application looks much better but what I am not able to achieve is arranging my view-points such that it creates the 3D effect like attached images. These images are of AcrossAir AR (http://www.acrossair.com/acrossair_app_augmented_reality_browser_for_iPhone_3GS.htm) application.

If you look these images, you could feel that all the available(predefined) map-points are displayed on a giant view and you can smoothly move points up and down with finger touch.

I have two questions. If someone can help me in any way that would be really appreciated. I have researched enough but finally gave up and stuck in my application.

Q1: What I have done is every time iPhone heading changes, I calculate and display the visible points so it happens that when you move iPhone you can feel that some points added and couple of points removed which doesn't happen in AcrossAir application. I want to create a View like AcrossAir in given pictures so that user doesn't feel addition/removal of points and moving points should be smooth.

Q2: If you already noticed from the pictures then it creates a 3D kind of view for the view points when you make your iPhone ***almost*** horizontal. For my implementation this doesn't happen, it always shows couple of points at a time. You have to use your finger to move points up and down. If you could give your thoughts on how could I implement this 3D kind functionality then it would be great.

Any inputs on this would be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

[image: Image 1 on my iPhone]
[image: Image 2 on my iPhone]
[image: Image 3 on my iPhone]